# Binomial Distribution Question using Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

For this question, I have a general idea of what's going on. The question is: a person typing a document has an error rate of 3 words per 1000 words. If this person typed 6 documents, each with 1000 words (number of errors being independent of each other), what is the probability that 5 documents contain at least 1 error.

First of all, to calculate the probability of 1 document containing at least 1 error, we get calculate the conjugate of $1-$probability of getting $0$ errors. This is equivalent to $\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^0}{0!}$, where $\mu = \frac{3}{1000}$.

Next, I will take the probability of what we just found and apply it to a Binomial Distribution of Binom($5$, $p$), because this question asks for the probability of 5 documents having at least 1 error.

I wanted to ask if my findings and calculations are on the right path. Any help would be appreciated ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but the Poisson parameter is 3...not 3/1000.

On a given page the probability of at least one error is

$1-\frac{e^{-3}3^0}{0!}=1-0.0498=0.9502$, so the probability that $5$ documents have at least $1$ error (and presumably the 6th page has no errors) is

$\binom{6}{5} \; 0.9502^5 \; (0.0498)^1 = 0.2314$

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense!! :D